# ssh server bash -c "cd /tmp && git pull" , cd does not work, need to add echo first

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm on ubuntu 15.04, my version of ssh client is

`OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015`

When I try to run the following command  `ssh admin@server bash -c 'cd /path/to/repo && git pull'`  the cd is not effective and i got

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

However If I do

`ssh admin@server bash -c 'echo test && cd /path/to/repo && git pull'`

then it works

```
Already up-to-date.
```

Of course I'm well aware `echo` is not supposed to change anything but after trying several time, several days on several different servers (though all on debian) I'm now sure to have this error.
On other servers I tried the command `cd /tmp && pwd` , and I got my home directory,  and if i do `echo toto && /tmp && pwd` I go `/tmp` printed...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, ssh passes through a single command line string to `$SHELL -c` on the remote. Your quotes aren't being effective.

When you run

```
ssh admin@server bash -c 'cd /path/to/repo && git pull'
```

this is being run on the remote server (with `$SHELL -c`):

```
bash -c cd /path/to/repo && git pull
```

So Bash is given single command (`cd`) and an unused argument, and then separately, you're also running `git pull` in the home directory.

On the other hand, when you run

```
ssh admin@server bash -c 'echo test && cd /path/to/repo && git pull'
```

this is being run on the remote server:

```
bash -c echo test && cd /path/to/repo && git pull
```

The first part is again useless, but the shell running the whole command then does `cd /path/to/repo` and `git pull`. Which works.

What you probably want to do is

```
ssh admin@server 'cd /path/to/repo && git pull'
```

Comment: Captain Nitpick checking in: The OpenSSH server uses the account's login shell to run remote commands, not necessarily /bin/sh. Aside from that, I think you're spot on.

Comment: @Kenster That's a good nitpick, though, because it makes a difference (such as when the user is locked down with `chsh -s /bin/nologin` or similar). Editing.

Answer (score 2):

The [existing answer by ephemient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43645287/14122) is entirely correct in terms of cause.

To add an alternate solution -- one which works when your remote code contains constructs which `sh -c` will misinterpret -- consider:

```
repo=/path/to/repo                 ## here, this works even when your path contains
                                   ## nonprintable or otherwise surprising characters
printf -v repo_q '%q' "$repo"      ## ...because we're asking your local copy of bash
                                   ## to generate a quoted/escaped copy of the value
                                   ## that will 'eval' back to its original meaning
                                   ## when interpreted by bash

## to ensure that it's interpreted by bash, we pass 'bash -s' as the command to ssh
## with an *unquoted* heredoc (<<EOF, vs <<'EOF'), with the escaped value expanded
ssh admin@server 'bash -s' <<EOF
cd $repo_q && git pull
EOF
```

Comment: Yep, that's a good and safe way to do it, although it can annoying to not be able to use stdin anymore. But there's other workarounds for that, such as `ssh admin@server "bash -c 'cd $(printf %q "$repo") && git pull'`

Comment: @ephemient, ...the issue there is that `printf '%q'` can generate `$''` quoting, which the shell expanding the outer command may not properly grok; hence keeping the results out of the command and limiting it to stdin. You're right that it's a tradeoff, though.

Comment: Oh, good point, that is problematic. I suppose `ssh admin@server "bash -c $(printf %q "cd $(printf %q "$repo") && git pull")"` would be a workaround for *that*, as everything from the first `printf` should be a printable character.