# Error running python over ssh - python3: can't open file 'run.py ': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: bash, ssh

I am attempting to run a bash script with the following command.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -i (path_to_key_file) (username)@(remote_address) "cd ~/scripts/section; python3 run.py"
```

When I run the script I get the following error

```
python3: can't open file 'run.py ': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

However, when I copy the line of code, paste it in a terminal, and run it, the code will successfully be run remotely.

I am not sure what could be causing the ssh call to fail when run from a bash script.

Comment: This is more a bash question than a python question. There are quite a few similar questions. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43645127/ssh-server-bash-c-cd-tmp-git-pull-cd-does-not-work-need-to-add-echo-fi or (from the unix SE site): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80821/why-does-cd-command-not-work-via-ssh

Comment: Is there a `~/scripts/section/run.py` file on the remote machine?

Comment: @Nic3500 Yes, that file exists on the remote machine.